# How can I make USB-to-Serial adapter faster, ReadFile taking too long to execute

Tags: c, windows, winapi, arduino, uart

I am trying to communicate with an Arduino every 1ms. Arduino is doing just fine at sending commands but my PC wont read data every 1ms. It usually takes 3 - 4ms and by that time my Arduino has already sent a bunch of data.

I tried to use `EV_RXCHAR` or `EV_CTS` but its the same, way too much time for Windows to respond to commands.

```
t = clock();
ReadFile(hComm, &s, sizeof(s), &NoBytesRead, NULL);
t = clock() - t;
double time_taken = ((double)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // in seconds usualy 0.003
```

I am not sure if the problem is in Windows drivers or the USB-to-UART ch340 chip.

Maybe you can recommend me some other way of doing communication at 1ms intervals?

Comment: Why not just read data as quickly as you can?

Comment: in general you need set [*serial timeouts*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddser/ns-ntddser-_serial_timeouts)

Comment: What is the communication rate (e.g.what is the baud)?  How much data (bytes) is being sent?

Comment: windows is NOT a real-time OS.  so it cannot keep up with 1ms between messages. (as you have found)  Even so, to maximize the amount of time available to process a message, a message needs to be 'double buffered' so the prior message can be processed while a new message is being received.  An important consideration is: How much data is being received in each message? what is the baud rate?  Note: 9600 baud takes approx. 1ms per character

Comment: Baud is set to 2Mbits i am sanding 8bytes every 1ms. I know windows is not good option for real time but i want to make this work with matlab/simulink. Plus i use usb-to-serial adapter and thas adds latency im sure. Well im stuck for now maybe ill try it on linux with real com port on MB.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the future reference.
The "problem" was in the USB 1.1 polling rate.
Max USB 1.1 polling rate is 1000Hz so the latency of sub 1ms is just not possible with ch340 (arduino's chip)...
USB 2.0 probably would work because of the 8khz polling rate.